# How Do I Pass Parameters To An OnClick Event Generated By a Dynamic Table Inside a Web Socket Event Using An EventListener

Tags: javascript, websocket, addeventlistener, dynamic-tables

I have seen this issue on this site, as well as, scouring through the internet but feel that this case is unique. I have a couple of things going on here. The first is that this page accepts web socket messages. Next, I'm creating a table dynamically with the last cell using onClick. To further complicate matters I am trying to pass a parameter to my function called by onClick. If I don't pass any parameters it works fine. When someone clicks on the image I want to pass the original JSON to my function. This, of course, does not work. The web browser console shows evt and p1 as undefined. Even though, I have added EventListener for the click action. My guess is that I am passing parameters incorrectly in my EventListener but there is so much going on that I'm not sure what is causing the issue. Does anyone know why my clickMessageOne function is not being called?

```
window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
window.addEventListener("click", function (e) {clickMessageOne(e, p1)}, false); // doesn't work
```

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    
    function init()
    {
        doConnect()
    }

    function doConnect()
    {
        websocket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.198:8000/");
        websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
        websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
        websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
        websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };
    }

    function onOpen(evt)
    {
        console.log("connected\n");
    }

    function onClose(evt)
    {
        console.log("disconnected\n");
    }

    function clickMessageOne(txt)
    {
        console.log("clickMessageOne");

        // txt should be original json
        console.log(txt);
    } 

    function onMessage(evt)
    {
        console.log("incomingJSON: " + evt.data + '\n');

        var recvObj = JSON.parse(evt.data);

        if (recvObj.code == "test")
        {
            var table = document.getElementById("incomingTable");
            var row = table.insertRow(1);

            // 7 columns
            var id = row.insertCell(0)
            var testOneCell = row.insertCell(1);
            var testTwoCell = row.insertCell(2);
            var testThreeCell = row.insertCell(3);
            var testFourCell = row.insertCell(4);
            var testFiveCell = row.insertCell(5);
            var testSixCell = row.insertCell(6);
            var testSevenCell = row.insertCell(7);
            var testEightCell = row.insertCell(8);

            id.innerHTML = ""
            testOneCell.innerHTML = "Incoming";
            testTwoCell.innerHTML = recvObj.number;
            testThreeCell.innerHTML = "";
            testFourCell.innerHTML = recvObj.time;
            testFiveCell.innerHTML = "";
            testSixCell.innerHTML = recvObj.textOne;
            testSevenCell.innerHTML = recvObj.textTwo;

            console.log(evt.data) // prints JSON correctly

            testEightCell.innerHTML = "<center><img src='test.png' onclick='clickMessageOne(evt.data)'></center>";
        } 
    }

    function onError(evt)
    {
        websocket.close();
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
    window.addEventListener("click", function (e) {clickMessageOne(e, p1)}, false); // doesn't work

    function doDisconnect() {
        websocket.close();
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Your function is expecting a single variable `txt`, but your function call is passing two variables `e, p1`, which means once the function is called and the variables `e, p1` are passed to it `txt=e`.

Comment: Also, you probably need a callback because the JSON data shows up at some arbitrary time, and when the eventListener is registered the data isn't there yet.

Comment: Dshiz, you were correct. Thank You.